# C-plus-plus coding errors

Tags: c++, oop, compiler-errors

I am learning C++ and I have to complete an Object Oriented Program. I am struggling to understand why I am getting an error. Please give as much as detail as possible when explaining because it would be helpful in the journey of teaching myself C++. Below is my initial code and the error:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class RectangularCube { //Defined the class Rectangular Cube
    private: //Access specifier - Declare two sides as private data field
        string color; //Private data field color that is string type
        double width;
        double height;

    public:
    double length; //Declare one side as a public data field

    //Contructor with parameteres
    RectangularCube(string newColor, double newWidth, double newHeight, double newLength) {
        color = newColor;
        width = newWidth;
        height = newHeight;
        length = newLength;
    }

    RectangularCube() { //No-arguments contructor with all three sides and color set to different values
        color = black;
        width = 5.145;
        height = 4.894;
        length = 10.123;
    }

    // Return Volume of this Rectangular Cube
    double getVolume() {
        return length * width * height;
    };

    //Return Surface Area of this Rectangular Cube
    double getSurfaceArea() {
        return 2(length * width) + 2(length * height) + 2(width * height)
    };
    
    //get and set functions for the two private sides and color data field
    double getColor();
    double getWidth();
    double getHeight();
    void setColor();
    void setWidth();
    void setHeight();

};

int main() {
    RectangularCube rectangularcube1();

    cout << "The Volume of the Rectangular Cube is: "
        << rectangularcube1.getVolume() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The Error

```
            color = black;
                    ^
RectangularCube.cpp:35:21: error: called object type 'int' is not a function or function pointer
            return 2(length * width) + 2(length * height) + 2(width * height)
                   ~^
RectangularCube.cpp:35:41: error: called object type 'int' is not a function or function pointer
            return 2(length * width) + 2(length * height) + 2(width * height)
                                       ~^
RectangularCube.cpp:35:62: error: called object type 'int' is not a function or function pointer
            return 2(length * width) + 2(length * height) + 2(width * height)
                                                            ~^
4 errors generated.
```

Comment: A cube is a cube. A rectangle is a completely different shape. They don't even share the same dimensionality.

Comment: FYI -- You forgot `#include <string>`.

Comment: A few more small things, dont use `using namespace std;` and try to pass objects like string as const references `const std::string&`. Your current code will have to copy the content of the std::string on each call. `getSurfaceArea` could be a const function (add const at the end of line) since it will not change any of the member variables, and to multiply by 2 you have to type `2*(x*y)`. And usually you can just use `\n` instead of `std::endl` (std::endl does more then add a newline and takes a bit more time)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By

```
2(length * width)
```

I assume you really mean

```
2*(length * width)
```

and this

```
 color = black;
```

should probably be

```
color = "black";
```

Comment: This is a comment.

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe No it isn't, it is two solutions.

Comment: wow, I am ashamed. this worked well. Thank you!

Comment: OP happy all happy.

Comment: @user207421 maybe he meant his comment was a comment on pm’s answer. It’s like when you write a test that says “this is a test “

Answer (score 2):

you have a total of three errors in this piece of code.

1. at non parameterized  constructor you didn't use black as a string
2. in getSurfaceArea function didn't use the * operator for multiplying before brackets.
3. when you create a new object with the name rectangularcube1 , you use (), which is used for the calling function.

**C++:**

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class RectangularCube { //Defined the class Rectangular Cube
private: //Access specifier - Declare two sides as private data field
    string color; //Private data field color that is string type
    double width;`enter code here`
    double height;

public:
    double length; //Declare one side as a public data field

    //Contructor with parameteres
    RectangularCube(string newColor, double newWidth, double newHeight, double newLength) {
        color = newColor;
        width = newWidth;
        height = newHeight;
        length = newLength;
    }

    RectangularCube() { //No-arguments contructor with all three sides and color set to different values
        color = "black";  // here you din't write black in string (with double quotes)
        width = 5.145;
        height = 4.894;
        length = 10.123;
    }

    // Return Volume of this Rectangular Cube
    double getVolume() {
        return length * width * height;
    };

    //Return Surface Area of this Rectangular Cube
    double getSurfaceArea() {
        return 2*(length * width) + 2 * (length * height) + 2 * (width * height);  // you din't use *  operator before brackets
    };

    //get and set functions for the two private sides and color data field
    double getColor();
    double getWidth();
    double getHeight();
    void setColor();
    void setWidth();
    void setHeight();

};

int main() {
    RectangularCube rectangularcube1; // you created new object with name rectangluarcube1 but you were using parenthesis like => rectangularcube1();   which is  a function call

    cout << "The Volume of the Rectangular Cube is: "
        << rectangularcube1.getVolume() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```